# Instantiate different objects based on state of some variable (without factory method)

Tags: c++, factory

I am trying to instantiate a different type of object, depending on the state of some variable. I think the official way to do this is with something called a factory method; but that is beyond my current skill level and so I am looking for a quick-and-dirty way to do this.

In the code below, the `solver` object should be instantiated based on the state of the `solverType` variable.

```
#include <appropriateHeaders.h>

int main() {
    // pseudocode representing the solverType being set
    std::string solverType;
    read_solverType_from_file(solverType);

    // actual code from my program; though in reality there are about 12 options
    if (solverType == "SimplicialLLT") {
        Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
    } else if (solverType == "SimpliciaLDLT") {
        Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with the above code of course is that the `solver` variable goes out of scope at the end of the if block. So is there a way to accomplish this goal (without resorting to factory methods)?

One option might be just to write out the twelve different options, and then comment out all but the one I want to use. But if I can do this using logic statements, I'd prefer to!

Thanks.

Comment: A side note: your `solver` will get out of scope (and get destructed) in the first `}` following its definition.

Comment: Oh! Yes that was the whole point of my question! The solver goes out of scope. Then in the process of cutting extra sentences, apparently I cut that key detail! Thank you. I've edited the question.

Comment: The usual solution is to have a base class from which all the solvers derive, and then use a [smart] pointer to base which is instatiated with one of the derived classes. But since you don't have control over the Eigen classes, this is probably not applicable in your case.

Comment: Yes! That is exactly my question. Thank you so much. I apologize in that I am an applied mathematician and so sometimes I have difficulty framing coding questions in a way that captures the essential details.

Comment: "official way to do this is with something called a factory method" It isn't "official". "Factory method" is just the name for what you are trying to do: create an object from some data.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution would probably be to use a templated function:

```cpp
template<typename SOLVER> 
void solve(SOLVER solver) {
    //...
}
int main() {
    // pseudocode representing the solverType being set
    std::string solverType;
    read_solverType_from_file(solverType);

    // actual code from my program; though in reality there are about 12 options
    if (solverType == "SimplicialLLT") {
        Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
        solve(solver);
    } else if (solverType == "SimpliciaLDLT") {
        Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> solver;
        solve(solver);
    }
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be a templete? You can just define `void solve(Eigen::SimplicialLLT);` and `void solve(Eigen::SimplicialLDLT);` 
C++ has function overloading, so it will pick the right function for you.

Comment: @habrewning: the whole point of the question was to avoid having to write the same code multiple times (once for each type). If you overload based on the type you might aswell put the code in the if else branches directly.

Comment: Now I understand your point. It was not clear for me, what you intention with the template is. Maybe if you write an arbitrary example `solver.solve()` instead of `//...` it becomes more clear.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few challenges to master for you and for the C++ compiler.

When you define a variable `int x` somewhere in your control flow, the compiler makes space for an integer variable. This is the easierst and best way to define variables, because you don't have to pay attention to the memory management. The compiler does it for you: The memory is cleaned up when you leave the control structure, where the variable is defined. This happens at compile time already.

I name these variables *"stack variables"*, because technically they are stored on the stack. When you want to become a C++ developer you soon will have to learn what the stack is and how it works.

A technical requirement of all variables on the stack is that the size must be determined at compile time. In C++ this means, the type must be determined at compile time for all local variables. In your code this is not the case. You have `SimplicialLLT` or `SimplicialLDLT` depending on what `solverType` is.

If you want to use local stack variables, there is (nearly) no solution for you.

The alternative method how you can define variables are *"heap variables"*. For heap variables the compiler does not do the memory management for you. That means:

- You have to define heap variables with `new`
- You have to work with pointers.
- You have to free memory with `delete`.

You will often hear people saying things like you don't have to use pointers in C++ or you can write programs without dynamic memory. Both may be correct in languages like Java ow Python. In C++ this it is nearly never possible to work without pointers.

That been accepted means you have to change your code drastically.

```
#include <appropriateHeaders.h>

int main() {
    // pseudocode representing the solverType being set
    std::string solverType;
    read_solverType_from_file(solverType);
    
    Simplicial * solver = 0;

    // actual code from my program; though in reality there are about 12 options
    if (solverType == "SimplicialLLT") {
        solver = new Eigen::SimplicialLLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
    } else if (solverType == "SimpliciaLDLT") {
        solver = new Eigen::SimplicialLDLT<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>>();
    }
    // Here you can have more code, that does something with the solver.
    // For example:
    if (solver)
      solver->solver();
    // At the end you have to clean up the memory.
    if (solver)
      delete solver;
}
```

Let me summarize what this means for you.

1. You have to define a parent class for Eigen::SimplicialLLT and Eigen::SimplicialLDLT.
2. The parent class (most likely) needs a virtual destructor.
3. You define `solver` as a pointer variable and initialises it with 0.
4. When creating the instances of the solver you must do this with `new`.
5. When working with the solver, you must always keep in mind, that it can be still zero. So you probably need a nullpointer check everywhere.
6. When working with the solver, you can only use methods, that are defined in the parent class. So that means, you are forced to pull the common interface, that you want to use into the parent class.
7. When working with the solver, you must use the `->` operator instead of the `.` operator. For example `solver->solve()`
8. At the end you must free the memory with `delete`

If you are not in control of the Eigen classes, you must write your own wrapper class.  When you see the [documentation of SimplicialLDLT](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1SimplicialLDLT.html), you will see that there is already a base class
`Eigen::SimplicialCholeskyBase`. This may work if it has a virtual desctructor or if it has been implemented in a way where it does not need a virtual constructor. This is what you will have to find out.

I am sorry for saying, that it is so complicated. This is the price when working with C++. There are a few concepts (like smart pointers) that simplifies everything a bit. But they are never 100% safe, so you must understand the basics of memory management before beeing able to work with smart pointers. It is a good thing that in C++ you are forced to pay attention to all these technical stuff, so that you can develop software that does many things upfront at compile time so that the execution is fast. But it is the bad thing, that all this is not easy. Java, C#, Python, Kotlin, Clojure and many other languages have a garbage collector for that purpose. Without a garbage collector there is a big piece of work that you as a developer must have under control.